# Javascript heavily executed functions: inline or declared?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, optimization

Is it safe to assume that for time critical applications it is always better to use function declaration or function expressions, instead of inline functions in heavily executed callbacks?

Consider following test program:

```
var x;
var count3 = function count3() {
    x++;
}

var count2 = function () {
    x++;
}

function count() {
    x++;
}

function execute(cb) {
    cb();
}

x = 0;
var a = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    execute(function named() {
        x++;
    })
}
a = new Date().getTime() - a;
console.log("Named inline function: " + a);
x = 0;
a = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    execute(function () {
        x++;
    })
}

a = new Date().getTime() - a;
console.log("Anonymous inline function: " + a);
x = 0;
a = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    execute(count);
}

a = new Date().getTime() - a;
console.log("Function declaration: " + a);
x = 0;
a = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    execute(count2);
}

a = new Date().getTime() - a;
console.log("Anonymous function expression:" + a);
x = 0;
a = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    execute(count3);
}

a = new Date().getTime() - a;
console.log("Named function expression:" + a);
```

This gives following output (in ms):

```
Named inline function: 2347
Anonymous inline function: 2121
Function declaration: 771
Anonymous function expression:750
Named function expression:752
```

Function declaration and function expressions are 3 times faster than inline functions on my humble laptop.

Comment: If this can be generalized? eg. always try to use function declaration instead of inline function in heavily executed callbacks

Comment: Put your code through http://jshint.com and yes, you shouldn't inline functions inside loops.

Comment: Might get better answers on [**Stack Exchange Code Review**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Ghillied: Why? It's a valid question here, and he does not really have code to review. The timing test suite and its results might have fit better in an answer, but they're OK.

Comment: @SeppVanRompaey - Why don't you use [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/ "jsPerf: JavaScript performance playground") or [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/ "Benchmark.js")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be generalized. Technically the function expression in the loop body is re-evaluated to a new function object every loop turn. As your tests confirm, this is noticeable slower (for millions of iterations) than having one "static" function defined outside the loop. Whether the function is named or not does not really matter, it has a very little overhead in introducing another variable in the execution contexts.

However, this is only relevant when the function really is declared inside the iteration, as in your examples. If you instead had a

```
function executeAll(cb) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        cb();
    }
}
```

then there be no difference between

```
executeAll(function() { x++; });
```

and

```
function increase() { x++; }
executeAll(increase);
```

since the `cb` argument is the "static" reference to the *one* function.

Comment: @Sepp: Depends. If you mean that the event is fired very often, then no. The `addEventListener` acts like the `executeAll` in my extended answer.

Comment: So `server.on("data",function() { ... do processing ...} )`  is speedwise the same as `server.on("data",DoProcessing)` ?

Comment: Your reference to `executeAll`made the similarity clear to me. Thanks for your help.